# Writing complex classes to file?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, system.reflection

I am learning the ins and outs of Entity Framework right now and being a practical learner I just wrote some simple examples of the kind of stuff that I'm looking at in C# and went through the classes in Visual Studio's Object Explorer ("tooltip").

This is however quite confusing at times and I was wondering if I can't just print out the stuff that I have and look at all of it at once.

I tried using Newtonsoft.Json but it tells me it can't deal with that kind of data because of "self referencing loops" and stuff, which I guess makes sense, considering the type of objects that I'm looking at .

Is there a way to enumerate the different kinds of ItemCollections (EdmItemCollection, ObjectItemCollection, etc), MetaDataWorkSpaces, and what else   there is, and print them out? Or am I forced to go back to theoretical learning?

Comment: `I can't just print out the stuff that I have` it is not clear what you are asking, can you post an example and your problem

Answer (score 1):

You should use a **watch**.

It allows you to look into the object structures while debugging.

It works better than the tooltip, and navigation is quite easy.

[image: watch]

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks!